# How to connect Lan (windows-rj45-Linux) to internet (Linux-usb-iPhone) without switch or router?

Tags: linux, iphone, windows, connection, lan

I have 2PC with windows and Linux. W connected to L via RJ-45.
Linux connected to IPhone with internet via USB.
How to connect LAN to Internet?
I don’t have any switch or router.  So I use common folder to work.

```
PC Lan  have  static local ip:
Linux: 192.168.0.1/24, gateway 192.168.0.2
Windows: 192.168.0.2/24, gateway 192.168.0.1
PC Web have automatic Ip.
```

I can ping Linux Internet IP from windows, but can’t ping google.
I tried bridge on linux: 192.168.0.1/24 , gateway internet Ip. And change gateway windows on internet Ip.
Tried bridge via Iproute2, but it was long ago.